# Nodejs ActiveDirectory relation user with computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory, ldap

I´m working with ActiveDirectory for a login and after the user is validate i will get all the values from that user but i dont know if is possible get the computers managed by that user.

My login and find user data is working this way:

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var {ConfigActiveDirectory} = require('./ConfigActiveDirectory.js');
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(ConfigActiveDirectory);

//Valida login y usuario en el dominio.
const ValidateLogin = (username,password,callback) =>{
    
    var username = username;
    var password = password;

    ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {

        if (err) {
            return callback(false);
        }
        if (auth) {
            return callback(auth);        
        }
        else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
}

const FindUser = (username,password,callback) =>{
    try {
    ConfigActiveDirectory.username = username;
    ConfigActiveDirectory.password = password;
    ad = new ActiveDirectory(ConfigActiveDirectory);
    ad.findUser(username, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        } else{
            console.log(user);
            return callback(user);
        }
    });   
    } catch (error) {
        return(error)
    }
}

exports.ValidateLogin = ValidateLog
```

in;
exports.FindUser = FindUser;

The function FindUser  return this values:

```
  userPrincipalName: 'cdeseda@deseda.com',
  sAMAccountName: 'deseda',
  mail: 'deseda@deseda.com',
  whenCreated: '20200622151737.0Z',
  pwdLastSet: '132445798065951322',
  userAccountControl: '512',
  sn: 'Deseda',
  givenName: 'Carlos',
  cn: 'Carlos Deseda',
  displayName: 'Carlos Deseda'
```

But nothing about the computer, on my active directory i added the user to the computer attribute and i can see the user like this:

> (Computer: ComputerDeseda) managedBy : CN=Carlos
> Deseda,OU=Desda,DC=deseda,DC=deseda

but i don't know how create the relation user-computer. I really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a user account in the "managedBy" attribute of a computer, the computer will show up in the "managedObjects" attribute for the user.

You might also check out the [msDS-PrimaryComputer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-msds-primarycomputer) attribute -- that's used in group policy processing when you elect to only redirect folders on the user's primary computer (i.e. something that *may* already be populated for your users).